# Iterating over two lists at the same time and try to find if a number in one list is bigger than items in the other list

Tags: python, list, sequence

(Sorry if my title is confusing. I am not sure how to describe this problem)

I have two lists in the following format:

```
list_a = [[10, 1], [25, 2]] # list sorted base on the first element of each pair
list_b = [3, 14, 5, 26]
```

I am trying to see at which point the sum of items in `list_b` is greater than items in `list_a[i][0]`, if so, add `list_a[i][1]` to the sum. Think of playing a game and getting the points in `list_b`, and getting bonus points when you reach certain point totals as specified in `list_a`.

My intended output is a sequence of number. For the above example:

```
# [3, 3+14+1, 3+14+1+5, 3+14+1+5+26+2]
# 3+14+1 because 3+14 is greater than 10
# 3+14+1+5+26+2 because 3+14+1+5+26 is greater than 25
[3, 18, 23, 51]
```

My attempt:

```
sum_b = 0 # used to track sum of items in list_b
output_list = []

for i in list_a:
  for j in list_b:
    # go over list b to get current sum
    sum_b += j

    if sum_b > i[0]: # when I see sum_b > i[0], I add i[1] to sum_b
      sum_b += i[1] 
    output_list.append(sum_b)
    # I want to keep going through the list to see when sum_b gets greater than 25 and add 2 to sum_b
```

Comment: list b is not getting changed so its better to calculate the sum of items in list b once rather than inside for loop

Comment: This isn't very clear. For example, what do you mean by "keep track of `list_a[1]`"? What is the intended output?

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for the advice. I just edited the question.

Comment: You still didn't say what the intended output was. It still isn't very clear. You use phrases like "adjust the number" when you have a great many numbers in play. What number are you referring to?

Comment: @KiwiFT add sample input and corresponding output please.

Comment: So is it just add `list_a[i][1]` to `sum_b`...? Or did you want to stop summing `list_b` when `list_a[i][0]` is met and add the second element?

Comment: @r.ook yes it is to add `list_a[i][1]` to `sum_b` when `sum_b` is greater than `list_a[i][1]`. I also need to use `sum_b` as I am going through `list_b`

Comment: @Ch3steR I am looking for a way to keep track the sum of `list_b` and add `list_a[i][1]` to it when I see the sum is greater than `list_a[i][0]`. I want to use the sum of `list_b` within the for loop.

Comment: Why stubbornly refuse to provide the sample output?

Comment: @HeapOverflow because I am also trying to figure out what is the output here...

Comment: It's still not clear. What do you mean by "the point at which the sum of items in list_b"? The sum of the items in list_b is the sum of all the items; it doesn't change unless you change the list contents. What do you mean by "greater than items in list_a[i][0]"? That's a single integer, not a list; and "greater than items" still isn't clear - do you mean, for example, greater than *all of* the items? or greater than *some item*?

Comment: So you don't even understand the problem yourself? Then how are *we* supposed to understand it and do anything meaningful?

Comment: If *you* don't know what the intended output is, this question is premature.

Comment: "I am also trying to figure out what is the output here". So you have some numbers that don't have a meaning you can explain, and you don't know what answer you should get for the example values, even for a small example? In this case, *how do you know that you need to solve the problem at all*?

Comment: @HeapOverflow I am sorry for all the confusion. I am looking for a way to loop through these two lists at the same time. I want to update a variable within the loop and use the variable. I am having a hard time coming up a decent description of what I am thinking about....

Comment: For the given input, what is the *sequence* of values that "the variable" (`track`? `sum_b`?)  should take on?

Comment: I think it's best to focus your effort on figuring out the expected output and then [edit] your question with clarity, instead of providing half answers here.  Please see [ask].  Right now I'm not sure if you wanted to see is `[3, 17 + 1, 22 + 1, 48 + 1 + 2]`

Comment: @JohnColeman I understand. I am sorry for this confusion because in my head I am focusing on how to iterate and get the number within each iteration instead of having one output. I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: @r.ook Thank you for the advice. I tried to come up with a better description based on your comment. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Some of the comments were a bit harsh, but you might appreciate the frustration in trying to figure out your question and then realize you didn't understand it yourself... In any case I hope my answer is able to help you.

Comment: Could `list_a` also be `[[25, 2], [10, 1]]`? If yes, what should the output be then? If no, why not?

Comment: @HeapOverflow It would be a sorted list based on `i[0]`. Thank you for pointing that out. I have made the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staying close to your own attempt, but advancing your `i` through `list_a` properly. Here `i` is always the next unused pair of `list_a` (or `None` if there aren't any left), and I use it at the right point during the loop through `list_b`.

```
sum_b = 0 # used to track sum of items in list_b
output_list = []
iter_a = iter(list_a)
i = next(iter_a, None)

for j in list_b:
    # go over list b to get current sum
    sum_b += j

    if i and sum_b > i[0]: # when I see sum_b > i[0], I add i[1] to sum_b
        sum_b += i[1]
        i = next(iter_a, None)
    output_list.append(sum_b)
```

It only takes linear time, as I'm moving through both lists in parallel rather than in nested full-length loops.

Answer (score 2):

With your updated questoin, it seems you want to find the cumulative sum of `list_b` and add the second element of the inner `list_a` when the condition is met.  I'd suggest compile a list of the cumulative sum of `list_b` first, and then crosscheck `list_a` and add each second element that meets the requirement:

```
cumsum_b = [sum(list_b[:i+1]) for i in range(len(list_b))]

# [3, 17, 22, 48]

result = []
for s in cumsum_b:
    for n, i in list_a:
        if s > n:
            s += i
    result.append(s)

# [3, 18, 23, 51]
```

Comment: Best I can do atm.  Would have wanted a list comprehension instead but the compound adding complicates matter.

Comment: Hmm, mentioning list comprehension makes me think we're talking about a different inefficiency. I'm talking about this being O(n^2 + mn) while it can be done in O(m + n).